# Using display:table-cell without containing display:table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a semantically correct HTML 5 web page utilizing CSS 3. I've created the below markup which exists at the root of my `body` element. Applying `display:table-cell` to both the `aside` and `section` elements causes them to column as I would like them to. However, I have no containing element to apply a `display:table` to. Is it okay to use `display:table-cell` if the element which it is being applied to is not contained within a `display:table`? If not is there a better mechanism to create a column layout with these elements without using floats?

```
<aside>
    <nav>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<section>
    Content goes here
</section>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, it is valid.  Read [17.2.1 of CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) regarding anonymous table objects.  More specifically, these sections...

Generating missing child wrappers:

> 1. If a child C of a 'table' or
>      'inline-table' box is not a proper
>      table child, then generate an
>      anonymous 'table-row' box around C and
>      all consecutive siblings of C that are
>      not proper table children.
> 2. If a child
>      C of a row group box is not a
>      'table-row' box, then generate an
>      anonymous 'table-row' box around C and
>      all consecutive siblings of C that are
>      not 'table-row' boxes.
> 3. If a child C of
>      a 'table-row' box is not a
>      'table-cell', then generate an
>      anonymous 'table-cell' box around C
>      and all consecutive siblings of C that
>      are not 'table-cell' boxes.

Generate missing parents:

> 1. For each 'table-cell' box C in a
>      sequence of consecutive internal table
>      and 'table-caption' siblings, if C's
>      parent is not a 'table-row' then
>      generate an anonymous 'table-row' box
>      around C and all consecutive siblings
>      of C that are 'table-cell' boxes.
> 2. For
>      each proper table child C in a
>      sequence of consecutive proper table
>      children, if C is misparented then
>      generate an anonymous 'table' or
>      'inline-table' box T around C and all
>      consecutive siblings of C that are
>      proper table children. (If C's parent
>      is an 'inline' box, then T must be an
>      'inline-table' box; otherwise it must
>      be a 'table' box.)
>
>    - A 'table-row' is
>        misparented if its parent is neither a
>        row group box nor a 'table' or
>        'inline-table' box.
>    - A 'table-column'
>        box is misparented if its parent is
>        neither a 'table-column-group' box nor
>        a 'table' or 'inline-table' box.
>    - A row
>        group box, 'table-column-group' box,
>        or 'table-caption' box is misparented
>        if its parent is neither a 'table' box
>        nor an 'inline-table' box.

Answer (score 1):

From [**the CSS2.1 specs**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) :

> #### 17.2.1 Anonymous table objects
>
> Document languages other than HTML may not contain all the elements in
> the CSS 2.1 table model. In these cases, the "missing" elements must
> be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any table element
> will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around
> itself, consisting of at least three nested objects corresponding to a
> 'table'/'inline-table' element, a 'table-row' element, and a
> 'table-cell' element. Missing elements generate [**anonymous**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous) objects
> (e.g., anonymous boxes in visual table layout)
>
> ...

What this means is that if we use `display: table-cell;` without first containing the cell in a block set to `display: table-row;`, the row will be implied — the browser will act as though the declared row is actually there.

So yes, using `display:table-cell` without containing `display:table` does produce valid CSS. That doesn't mean its behavior is stable, however. Even today (February 2016), the behavior of `display:table` and `display:table-cell` remains inconsistent across browsers. See [**Inconsistent behavior of display: table and display: table-cell**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327767/inconsistent-behavior-of-display-table-and-display-table-cell) for some examples.