# Using display:table-cell without table-row

Tags: html, css, css-tables, tablerow, tablecell

I recently noticed that it is possible to use `display: table-cell;` on an element without surrounding it with an element using `display: table-row;`

Example (working in IE, Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera):

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this considered bad style? Should the table-cell be surrounded by a table-row or is it not necessary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using display:table-cell without containing display:table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379561/using-displaytable-cell-without-containing-displaytable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. It does not need to be used with `display: table-row`. Read [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#value-def-table-cell).

`table-cell` just represents a `<td>` or `<th>`:

> Specifies that an element represents a table cell.

And specifically regarding `table-cell`:

> For example, an image that is set to 'display: table-cell' will fill
>   the available cell space, and its dimensions might contribute towards
>   the table sizing algorithms, as with an ordinary cell.

Comment: I dont think this answers the OP's question.  Where in this documentation does it say that you dont need a containing display:table-row ?  HTML tables markup has always needed at least TABLE -> TR -> TD.  I have had problems in the past because of a missing display:table-row container, but I have not seen it for about a year now.  I wonder if modern browsers now allow you to have just a display:table with a display:table-cell.  Also, if the tr is now inferred automatically as an anonymous element, it would also be good to know whether you can just use a display:table-cell element on it's own.

Comment: [Using display:table-cell without containing display:table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379561/using-displaytable-cell-without-containing-displaytable) has a link to the doc, which says: "For each 'table-cell' box C in a sequence of consecutive internal table and 'table-caption' siblings, if C's parent is not a 'table-row' then generate an anonymous 'table-row' box around C and all consecutive siblings of C that are 'table-cell' boxes."

Comment: HTML may require TABLE -> TR -> TD if you are using actual table elements, but if you are just using css display values on divs, it may be different, because now we are outside the realm of HTML and in the realm of CSS.

Answer (score 15):

From [**Everything You Know About CSS Is Wrong**](http://64.13.255.16/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/) :

> #### Anonymous Table Elements
>
> CSS tables happily abide by the normal rules of table layout, which
>   enables an ex­tremely powerful feature of CSS table layouts: missing
>   table elements are created anonymously by the browser. The CSS2.1
>   specification states:
>
> > Document languages other than HTML may not contain all the ele­ments
> >     in the CSS 2.1 table model. In these cases, the “missing” elements
> >     must be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any table
> >     element will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects
> >     around itself, consisting of at least three nested objects
> >     corresponding to a “table”/“inline-table” element, a “table-row”
> >     element, and a “table-cell” element.
>
> What this means is that if we use `display: table-cell;` without first
>   containing the cell in a block set to `display: table-row;`, the row
>   will be implied—the browser will act as though the declared row is
>   actually there.

So no, there's nothing wrong with using `display:table-cell` without containing `display:table-row`. The CSS it produces is perfectly valid and has some very interesting use cases. For more info on using anonymous table Elements, see the article I'm quoting from.

---

#### Note :

The fact that it produces valid CSS doesn't mean that the behavior of `display:table-cell` without `display:table-row` or `display:table-row` is stable. Even today (February 2016), the behavior of anoymous table elements remain inconsistent across browsers. See [**Inconsistent behavior of display: table and display: table-cell**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327767/inconsistent-behavior-of-display-table-and-display-table-cell) for more details.