# How to align between text and child node with CSS?

Tags: css

I have HTML of the form

```
<div class="display_archive">
  <div class="campaign">05/01/2016 - <a href="omitted">Back from the Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/28/2016 - <a href="omitted">Special prayer request: Go Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/26/2016 - <a href="omitted>Go Go Year of Big Changes</a></div>
</div>
```

which looks like

> 05/01/2016 - **Back from the Philippines**
>   02/28/2016 - **Special prayer request: Go Philippines**
>   02/26/2016 - **Go Go Year of Big Changes**

Without changing the HTML, how can I use CSS to align it along the hyphen `-`? For example, if I wanted to align that hyphen at 1/3 of the containing `div, it might look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table` with `margin: 0 auto` on parent.

```css
.display_archive {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="display_archive">
  <div class="campaign">05/01/2016 - <a href="omitted">Back from the Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/28/2016 - <a href="omitted">Special prayer request: Go Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/26/2016 - <a href="omitted">Go Go Year of Big Changes</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be doing a different thing from what I had in mind, but I think I like it more. If you were to describe it outside the context of my question, what would you call it?

Comment: Not sure  what you mean, you just center parent element or `display_archive` in this case relative to `body`. You can do the same thing like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1254/ but i think other solution is better.

Comment: If you googled this concept to learn more about it, what would you google?

Answer (score 0):

You can align the anchor tags, instead of the hyphens, like this:

```css
.display_archive {
  display: table;
}
.campaign {
  display: table-row;
}
.campaign a {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="display_archive">
  <div class="campaign">05/01/2016 - <a href="omitted">Back from the Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/28/2016 - <a href="omitted">Special prayer request: Go Philippines</a></div>
  <div class="campaign">02/26/2016 - <a href="omitted">Go Go Year of Big Changes</a></div>
</div>
```

It makes the browser treat the outter div like a table and defines your anchor tags as cells. This makes the browser render the text before your anchor tag like a (preceding) table cell. As such, all your anchor tags are aligned in the same (2nd) column.

Here are some useful info on `display: table` for further reading:

- http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero
- [Inconsistent behavior of display: table and display: table-cell in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327767/inconsistent-behavior-of-display-table-and-display-table-cell-in-different-bro)
- http://64.13.255.16/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/

Note that you may have to check if this is supported on IE7 or lower if you need to support those browsers.