# Vertically center text within a rounded div

Tags: html, css

I've got two `divs` that are circles because of a `border-radius`. They are inline-blocks, and have multiple lines of text inside:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/hVNsZ/1/

However, I need to center these lines of text vertically within the div. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">this is a sentence</div>

<div class="circle">this is<br>multiple<br>lines</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to put display as 'table-cell' and use vertical-align:middle.
Here's the css:

```
.circle {
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
border-radius: 90px;
background-color: orange;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hVNsZ/6/

Comment: just curious.....using `display: table-cell;` without parent `display: table;` div is suggested???

Comment: @NoobEditor: Sure, you can do that. [Anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) are automatically generated to create a complete table structure.

Comment: Thanks, but how come these two are not centered with `margin: 0 auto` anymore? http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/hVNsZ/12/

Comment: Coz `text-align: center` is missing in ur fiddle. See this 1 http://jsfiddle.net/hVNsZ/13/

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` property will work only for the elements which are displayed `table-cell`

```
.circle {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;  //added
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle; //aligned middle
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hVNsZ/11/)

Comment: just curious.....using `display: table-cell;` without parent `display: table;` div is suggested???

Comment: @NoobEditor it won't cause you problem and it is a valid too

Comment: @NoobEditor I would suggest you to take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4379605/1671639) which brief table properties.